# Fazer o R esperar pelo utilizador

Tags: r, menu

Tenho um programa completo em R, em que primeiro pede um número ao utilizador, usando a função menu:

```
menu(c('1','2','3'),title='Escolha um numero')
```

De seguida, umas linhas de código abaixo, este número escolhido é necessário para algumas funções. É requerido que o programa seja o mais independente possível ou seja, utilizador faça "Run all", introduza o número e de seguida o programa corra sozinho e dê o resultado final.
O problema está que ao efetuar "Run all", o programa não espera que o utilizador introduza o número e executa um ciclo infinito ou seja o programa dá erro.
Existe alguma função que possa fazer o R esperar que o utilizador introduza o número e só de seguida continue o programa usando "Run all"?

Comment: Para mim seu código isoladamente deveria funcionar normalmente, mas não está claro o que você quer para além disso. Talvez seja interessante incluir mais linhas de código para alguém poder lhe ajudar.

Comment: O utilizador tem de escolher um número e só depois pode seguir o programa, o meu objetivo é que quando o utilizador faz "run all" o R espere que o utilizador introduza um número e depois continue.
Já tentei usar a função source para ir buscar a outro ficheiro assim como:
if interactive()==TRUE continuar o programa
if interactive()==FALSE voltar a perguntar
Mas continua a dar erro porque o R não espera a resposta

Comment: Já utilizou o Shiny para fazer uma interface com o usuário?

Comment: Não, vou procurar como se usa. Mas isso implica usar o Rstudio e eu tenho de trabalhar em R mas obrigada pela resposta.

Comment: Você ja experimentou usar  readline(prompt="Entre um número")

Comment: Sim já, mas não é esse o problema. A pergunta estava mal explicada, já editei penso que esteja mais clara agora

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro com função iterativa de menu quando corre código em bloco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205118/erro-com-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-iterativa-de-menu-quando-corre-c%c3%b3digo-em-bloco)