# Erro com função interativa de menu quando corre código em bloco

Tags: r, menu

Tenho uma linha de codigo que pede um número pedido ao utilizador assim:

```
menu(c('1','2','3'), title='Escolha um número:')
```

Mas que faz parte de um programa que utiliza esse número pedido em funções mais à frente.

Quando corro a linha de código separadamente funciona bem, ao correr em bloco lê cada linha de código como resposta a essa pergunta e portanto dá erro.

Já tentei:

```
scan("stdin", character(), n=1)
```

e

```
file("stdin")
```

Mas nada funciona.

Answer (score 3):

Rodar o código em bloco é a mesma coisa que mandar *interativamente* comandos para o console. Dessa forma, quando você roda o código em bloco, o `R` vai achar que a linha logo após `menu()` é a resposta para o `menu()`, pois o `R` apenas está recebendo cada comando iterativamente.

Entretanto, se você der `source()` no seu código você terá o comportamento que você quer.

Se você estiver usando o `RStudio`, uma maneira fácil de dar source é clicar no botão de "source" do script ou usar a tecla de atalho `crtl` (ou `cmd` para mac) + `shift` + `enter`.

Para dar source pela linha de comando, primeiramente você deve salvar o seu script e depois chamar `source("nomedoscript.R")`.

Para um exemplo mínimo, salve o código abaixo em `teste.R`:

```
rm( list = ls())
x <- menu(c('1','2','3'), title='Escolha um número:')
y <- x + 1
```

E em seguida rode `source("teste.R")`. Você verá que o o prompt aparecerá corretamente e  variável `y` terá o valor correto de `x+1`, o que não ocorre rodando em bloco.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, mas mesmo assim continua a dar erro.
Escrevi um ficheiro com a função menu, e depois no ficheiro completo onde tenho o resto do código fiz source("nomedoficheiro.R") mas mesmo assim o R continua a assumir cada linha de código como uma resposta à pergunta d a função menu

Comment: @Rita Esse exemplo mínimo que coloquei funciona no seu computador?

Comment: Sim, esse exemplo funciona @Carlos Cinelli

Comment: E quando corro a função "source" isoladamente no meu código funciona bem também. O problema está que esta função faz parte de um programa completo e quando uso "Run all", aí o código assume cada linha de código como resposta e dá erro

Comment: @Rita não entendi, mas você está rodando o "run all" ou o "source"? O run all não vai funcionar mesmo. Tenta criar um exemplo mínimo que reproduz o problema e colocar aqui.

Comment: Obrigada @Carlos Cinelli. Já consegui resolver o problema, como a escolha que eu quero era apenas entre três números, para usar a função menu e correr o programa com o "run all", basta acrescentar na função menu "graphics=TRUE"